# Typedef struct com vetor de caracteres em C não está funcionando

Tags: c, array, string, struct, memória

Estou tentando criar um tipo de dados construtivo, mas estou tendo problemas com as strings.

```
   typedef struct {
        char nome[30];
        int idade;
    } p;

    p x,y; 

    x.nome = “ana”;
    x.idade = 20;
    y.nome = “caio”;
    y.idade = 22;

    printf(“%s : %d”, x.nome, x.idade);
    printf(“%s : %d”, y.nome, y.idade);
```

Por que não posso fazer `x.nome = “ana”;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa usar [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) para copiar o conteúdo da *string* para dentro da estrutura no membro onde o *array* de `char` reservou espaço.

Você deve estar acostumado com outras linguagens que fazem a cópia para você quando faz  a atribuição. Em C você tem que fazer na mão.

[Se na estrutura fosse um ponteiro para `char` aí poderia colocar uma referência para o literal *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181609/101). Copiar um dado escalar (simples) é possível, um dado composto precisa ser copiado. Um ponteiro é escalar. Um sequência de caracteres é composto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char nome[30];
    int idade;
} p;

int main(void) {
    p x,y; 
    strcpy(x.nome, "ana");
    x.idade = 20;
    strcpy(y.nome, "caio");
    y.idade = 22;
    printf("%s : %d", x.nome, x.idade);
    printf("%s : %d", y.nome, y.idade);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/DtOUYm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ojmpxjib-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CopyToStruct.c).

Comment: Obrigado! Como ficaria o código caso fosse um ponteiro para 'char'?

Comment: Do jeito que você fez, só que o membro seria `char *nome`

Comment: @PauloDosSantos detalhe mais em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181609/101.