# Se array é o mesmo que ponteiro, por que um precisa ser copiado para uma variável e outro não precisa?

Tags: c, c++, array, ponteiro, memória

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/181560/101) o Maniero disse que se o membro da estrutura fosse um ponteiro não precisaria copiar a *string* para dentro dele. Mas *arrays* não são ponteiros? Por que é diferente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro, [*arrays* não são ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Eles servem para propósitos diferentes.

A principal diferença entre eles é que o *array* reserva espaço na memória para o seu valor, o ponteiro só reserva espaço para o próprio ponteiro. O valor estará em outro lugar apontado por aquele ponteiro. Executando este código podemos observar isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char *nome;
} Tipo1;

typedef struct {
    char nome[30];
} Tipo2;

int main(void) {
    Tipo1 x;
    Tipo2 y;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(x));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(y));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/8yXRYn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gpivdqga-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/ArrayXPointer.c).

O primeiro tem tamanho 4 porque o ponteiro é deste tamanho. A *string* terá que ser alocada em outro local. Ali você coloca o ponteiro. Ponteiro é um tipo escalar, é simples, é algo que o computador pode tratar diretamente. Você pode copiar um valor ali dentro da `struct` em uma operação simples.

Esse ponteiro pode apontar para qualquer lugar válido da memória. Poderia apontar para uma área da pilha, mas é raro. Em algumas situações pode apontar para a área estática da aplicação rodando. É o que ocorreu naquela pergunta. Mas isso não é tão comum assim porque essa *string* não pode ser mudada, ela está em área só de leitura. O mais comum é referenciar a memória no *heap* alocada por um [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).

Você pode trocar o valor desse membro da `struct` só mudando o ponteiro. Se o ponteiro originalmente apontava para uma área estática da memória e precisa mudar seu valor, obrigatoriamente terá que criar uma nova *string* e trocar o ponteiro por outro que aponte para essa nova *string*. Isto é necessário porque não podemos alterar área estática da memória.

Usar o ponteiro tem algumas vantagens, as principais:

- a *string* pode ter tamanho variável
- a *string* fica independente
- evita-se copiar a *string* para poder usá-la mais facilmente
- a `struct` fica menor por causa disto e talvez facilite usá-la como valor
- é possível alterar seu valor sem alterar outras referências para o valor antigo

É claro que existem desvantagens, a principal delas é que costuma ter que ficar gerenciando o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) dessa *string* associada.

O ponteiro cria uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

As duas formas podem ser usadas, dependendo do que deseja cada um pode ser o mais adequado.

No caso do *array* que é um tipo composto, isto é, ele possui vários valores juntos, ele é uma sequência de caracteres. O computador não sabe como manipular dados compostos, o seu código precisa fazer isto. Esta é a razão de precisar usar um `strcpy()` para copiar a *string* da área estática para dentro da *struct*.

A `struct` com um *array* no código acima tem tamanho 30, então você tem que colocar a *string* lá dentro. E é problema seu não deixar estourar esse limite. Nada impede colocar mais que 30 caracteres (incluindo o [terminador de *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101)), se ultrapassar esse limite provavelmente vai corromper a memória.

Este é um exemplo prático como esses dois tipos são muito diferentes, ainda que o *array* sempre seja acessado através de um ponteiro e o ponteiro sempre pode ser acessado com a sintaxe de *array*. Mas entenda que no fundo a linguagem só tem o ponteiro. O *array* é uma facilidade sintática e um meio de alocar memória.

Comment: O ponteiro de `char` aponta para vários endereços na memória já o vetor aponta para um único endereço e vários valores, estou certo e isso mesmo?

Comment: Não, o ponteiro (`char *`) aponta para **um** endereço. Esse endereço pode ser o início de uma sequência de dados (no casos uma sequência de caracteres), mas um ponteiro aponta para uma posição de memória. A gente sabe que haverá uma sequência, o computador não sabe. É problema nosso controlar isso. O *array* não deixa de ser um ponteiro e tudo isso vale para ele também, não há diferença. Só que o tipo *array* tem uma diferença para o tipo ponteiro, que é a forma como o conteúdo é alocado, o 1o. é alocado *inline*, no local onde é declarado e gera um ponteiro para esse local.

Comment: Já o ponteiro o seu código precisa dizer para onde ele deve apontar, talvez fazendo uma alocação antes. Aí pode pensar e se eu criar um ponteiro e acessar assim: `var[3]` aí ele virou *array*? Não, usou a sintaxe de *array* para acessar um ponteiro. `var[0]` é **um** ponteiro, `var[1]` é outro ponteiro. Não confunda ponteiro, *array* com os dados na memória. Leu a *link* inicial da resposta? Lá ajuda entender essa diferença e semelhante entre *array* e ponteiro.

Comment: Sim eu li, e um pouco difícil não fazer confusão entre eles, mas estou entendendo melhor. Se tivesse uma imagem que ilustrasse a diferença entre array e ponteiro seria bem melhor para visualizar pq e muito abstrato :)

Comment: Eu demorei anos pra entender por completo e nem sei se entendi 100% :) Vou ver se faço alguma coisa, mas na verdade não é fácil, porque eles são a mesma coisa concretamente :) O tipo é que é tratado diferentemente.

Comment: Ja faz quase dois anos que programo em C e ainda não entendi tbm :) Isso porque o array tem seus tipos, e espaços na memória serve para guarda endereços ou valores, isso que causa confusão certo?

Comment: É basicamente isto. Pense que só existe ponteiro e a sintaxe de *array* é só para ajudar fazer a aritmética de ponteiro. Se é ponteiro mesmo você tem o endereço de onde está o valor, se é *array* já referencia para o valor.  A única diferença mais importante é a alocação de memória. O *array* mesmo aloca memória onde ela está declarada. E obviamente que se o computador aloca, ele sabe o tamanho. Fora isso, só existe ponteiro, o resto é só uma sintaxe que parece ser *array*, aí acho que diminui a confusão.

Comment: @Maniero https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e4soWJvfxQ

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de ver é assim o ponteiro tem valor variável, ou seja ele pode apontar pra qualquer lugar da memória.
Já o vetor não é estático ele não muda nunca e se você tentar mudar vai ter problemas.

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

    char vetor[30] = "Jhonatan";
    char * ponteiro_vetor = vetor;

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(vetor));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(ponteiro_vetor));
    printf("%p\n", vetor);
    printf("%p\n", ponteiro_vetor);
    ponteiro_vetor = ponteiro_vetor + 1;
    printf("%p\n", ponteiro_vetor);
}
```

Mas se você tentar acessar um lugar invalido terá uma falha de segmentação.